# Defining control Id for windows resource compiler

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

Suppose I have a dialog box in windows defined by a rc file. I want to wrap the dialog interface into a C++ class

```
class MyDialog
    {
//...
    };
```

also, the control id:s should be defined as integer constants belonging to that class

```
class MyDialog
    {
    private:
        static const int MY_BUTTON=100;
    };
```

The resource compiler would not understand MyDialog::MY_BUTTON but #define MyDialog_MY_BUTTON 100 (since the preprocessor is used)

Is there a good way to use resource files without having all macors visible when not RC_INVOKED?

Comment: The resource compiler does not know how to compile C++ code.  You'll need to use #defines.

Comment: Yes but how #ifdef RC_INVOKED #define CONSTANT(x) #define x Cannot define to define :-(